Add a hook to the argument of a command based on its other arguments
Take \textcolor{#3}{#4} as a simple example. However, the actual command contains asterisked and optional arguments.

If the argument #3 is green or blue, then \textcolor{#3}{#4}
should produce something like \textcolor{#3}{This is green or blue #4}.
If not, the command should be left unchanged.

Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated.

what do you mean by Take \textcolor{#3}{#4} as a simple example.  what are #3 and #4 here, is this embedded in another definition? does this relate to the latex hook mechanism? Please clarify your question with a more complete example.

I find that this question no longer seems to apply to my original situations, where \textcolor is a command defined in some packages and has been used for many times.

sorry I don't understand your comment. \textcolor is a standard latex command defined by the color package, It's been used many times since I introduced it in 1993, but what's your question?

The command I use is not \textcolor, it is changed to \textcolor just to make the output more visible here. So the problem I'm having has nothing to do with \textcolor.

As far as I can guess, you are looking for something like

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand\foo{mmmm}{%
  [arg1:~ #1]~
  [arg2:~ #2]~
  \str_case:nnF{#3} {
    {green}{\textcolor{#3}{This~ is~ green~ #4}}
    {blue}{\textcolor{#3}{This~ is~ blue~ #4}}
    }
    {\textcolor{#3}{#4}}
}

\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}


\foo {1}{aa}{green}{some text}

\foo {2}{bb}{blue}{some text}

\foo {3}{cc}{red}{some text}

\end{document}

